# Mock is not working in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, mockito

I use Mockito to mock something and one the local machine the unit test ist working, but when executed on jenkins it seems like the mock did not fire, because the original code did execute and obviously failed.

I have a class OCSPConnector with the following method:

`public List<TSLOCSPResponse> getResponses(URL ocspServerUrl,
            TSLOCSPCertID certID) throws TSLOCSPException, TSLAPIError`

This is the mock creation:

```
// mock OCSP connector
        OCSPConnector ocspConnector = Mockito.mock(OCSPConnector.class);
        Mockito.when(ocspConnector.getResponses(Mockito.any(URL.class), Mockito.any(TSLOCSPCertID.class))).thenReturn(getFakeResponse(x509Certificate));
```

And this is the snippet showing the stack trace of the error with the execution of the original code (getResponses method) instead of the faked response:

```
    at de.gematik.tslapi.ocsp.TSLOCSP.sendHttpRequest(TSLOCSP.java:169) [GematikCommonPKI-0.9.4-SNAPSHOT-5553.jar:0.9.4-SNAPSHOT-5553]
at de.gematik.tslapi.ocsp.OCSPConnector.getResponse(OCSPConnector.java:128) [GematikCommonPKI-0.9.4-SNAPSHOT-5553.jar:0.9.4-SNAPSHOT-5553]
at de.gematik.tslapi.ocsp.OCSPConnector.getResponses(OCSPConnector.java:89) [GematikCommonPKI-0.9.4-SNAPSHOT-5553.jar:0.9.4-SNAPSHOT-5553]
```

As I said, locally on my dev machine it's working.

Any ideas?

Cheers Fireball

Comment: Your description is to broad and you need to add more details regarding your scenario, even code and log snippets if possible. How does it fail? Are you using mockito verifications to check interactions with the mock? If yes, is mockito complaining no interactions took place? Is there anything fishy in the execution log?

Comment: I use jenkins to execute my mockito tests and it works fine.
Can you add the error that you get and the code that did not work ?

Comment: Is the JDK that your dev and Jenkins machine using the same? I've had problems with mockito before where something gets broken in one version of java but gets fixed later on...